# Excel VBA run code on open in shared file

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a code that gives a message (or run a different code) on opening the workbook.

The file is shared through the old method of Excel (works better and faster) on a network folder. When im opening the file the message is given correctly, when someone else on our network is opening the same file he is not getting the message. Any idea why this is?

This is my code (in ThisWorkbook section)

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
MsgBox "Check for update complete"
End Sub
```

Comment: I was under the impression that excel files opened from network locations automatically blocked macros, i.e. any VBA code will not run. Have you checked the permissions for running macros? It is possible to make network files "trusted documents", which should solve this. Have you tried this?

Comment: Alternatively sign the code with a trusted company certificate, which should work too.

Comment: Yes its a trusted document @Prebus, i will try to sign it

Comment: signing it is not working for me @Pᴇʜ

Comment: *"is not working for me"* why not? • If the location of the document is trusted then check the macro permissions in Excel's trust center. What are the settings there (at the computer where it is not working)?